# Non-static method self::getModuleById() cannot be called statically on Joomla Module with php 8.0.1

Tags: php, methods, module, joomla

I have a Joomla Module it will produce an error code with php 8.0.1 on wampserver on helper.php line 121 "*Error Code: Non-static method modSidePanelHelper::getModuleById() cannot be called statically*". This is helper.php

```
    <?php
 
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';

if (!class_exists('LofPanelGroupBase')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/libs/group_base.php');
}

abstract class modSidePanelHelper {

    /**
     * get list articles
     */
    public static function getList($params) {
        if ($params->get('enable_cache')) {
            $cache = JFactory::getCache('mod_sidepanel_jt1');
            $cache->setCaching(true);
            $cache->setLifeTime($params->get('cache_time', 15) * 60);
            return $cache->get(array('modSidePanelHelper', 'getGroupObject'), array($params));
        } else {
            return self::getGroupObject($params);
        }
    }

    /**
     * get list articles
     */
    public static function getGroupObject($params) {
        $group = $params->get('group', 'file');
        $file = dirname(__FILE__) .'/libs/groups/'. strtolower($group) . '/' . strtolower($group) . '.php';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require_once($file);
            $className = 'SidePanelGroup' . ucfirst($group);
            if (class_exists($className)) {
                $object = new $className($group);
                $object->setCurrentPath(dirname(__FILE__) .'/libs/groups/'. strtolower($group) . '/');
            }
        }
        if ($object) {
            return $object->getListByParameters($params);
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }

    /**
     * load css - javascript file.
     * 
     * @param JParameter $params;
     * @param JModule $module
     * @return void.
     */
    public static function loadMediaFiles($params, $module, $theme='') {
        $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
        // if the verion is equal 1.6.x
        JHTML::script('modules/' . $module->module . '/assets/script.js');

        if ($theme && $theme != -1) {
            $tPath = JPATH_BASE .'/templates/'. $mainframe->getTemplate() .'/html/'. $module->module . '/' . $theme .'/assets/style.css';

            if (file_exists($tPath)) {
                JHTML::stylesheet('templates/' . $mainframe->getTemplate() . '/html/' . $module->module . '/' . $theme . '/assets/style.css');
            } else {
                JHTML::stylesheet('modules/' . $module->module . '/tmpl/' . $theme . '/assets/style.css');
            }
        } else {
            JHTML::stylesheet('modules/' . $module->module . '/assets/style.css');
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function renderItem(&$row, $params, $layout='_item') {
        $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
        $theme = $params->get('theme');

        $tPath = JPATH_BASE .'/templates/'. $mainframe->getTemplate() .'/html/mod_sidepanel_jt1/'. $theme . '/' . $layout . '.php';
        $bPath = JPATH_BASE .'/modules/mod_sidepanel_jt1/tmpl/'. $theme . '/' . $layout . '.php';

        if (file_exists($tPath)) {
            require($tPath);
        } elseif (file_exists($bPath)) {
            require($bPath);
        }
    }

    /**
     * load theme
     */
    public static function getLayoutByTheme($module, $group, $theme= '') {
        $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
        // Build the template and base path for the layout
        $tPath = JPATH_BASE .'/templates/'. $mainframe->getTemplate() .'/html/'. $module->module . '/' . $theme .'/default.php';
        $bPath = JPATH_BASE .'/modules/'. $module->module .'/tmpl/'. $theme .'/default.php';

        // If the template has a layout override use it
        if (file_exists($tPath)) {
            return $tPath;
        } elseif (file_exists($bPath)) {
            return $bPath;
        }
    }

    public static function getModulesEnable($params) {
        $enableModules = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
            $module = $params->get('file' . $i);
            if($module){
                if (intval($module->enable) == 1) {
                    $enableModules[] = self::getModuleById($module->image);
                }
            }
        }
        return $enableModules;
    }

    private function getModuleById($id) {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('module, title');
        $query->from('#__modules');
        $query->where('published=1 AND client_id=0 AND id=' . $db->quote($id));

        $db->setQuery($query);
        return $db->loadObject();
    }

    static function getReturnURL($params, $type) {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $router = $app->getRouter();
        $url = null;
        if ($itemid = $params->get($type)) {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            $query->select($db->quoteName('link'));
            $query->from($db->quoteName('#__menu'));
            $query->where($db->quoteName('published') . '=1');
            $query->where($db->quoteName('id') . '=' . $db->quote($itemid));

            $db->setQuery($query);
            if ($link = $db->loadResult()) {
                if ($router->getMode() == JROUTER_MODE_SEF) {
                    $url = 'index.php?Itemid=' . $itemid;
                } else {
                    $url = $link . '&Itemid=' . $itemid;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!$url) {
            // stay on the same page
            $uri = clone JFactory::getURI();
            $vars = $router->parse($uri);
            unset($vars['lang']);
            if ($router->getMode() == JROUTER_MODE_SEF) {
                if (isset($vars['Itemid'])) {
                    $itemid = $vars['Itemid'];
                    $menu = $app->getMenu();
                    $item = $menu->getItem($itemid);
                    unset($vars['Itemid']);
                    if (isset($item) && $vars == $item->query) {
                        $url = 'index.php?Itemid=' . $itemid;
                    } else {
                        $url = 'index.php?' . JURI::buildQuery($vars) . '&Itemid=' . $itemid;
                    }
                } else {
                    $url = 'index.php?' . JURI::buildQuery($vars);
                }
            } else {
                $url = 'index.php?' . JURI::buildQuery($vars);
            }
        }

        return base64_encode($url);
    }

}
```

line 121 is like this: `$enableModules[] = self::getModuleById($module->image);`

the self::getModuleById seems deprecated on php 8. Changing that line like this

```
$enableModules[] = (new modSidePanelHelper)->getModuleById($module->image);
```

causes another error code like this

*Error Code: Cannot instantiate abstract class modSidePanelHelper*

any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is deprecation information in this case?

Comment: It's like I remember something like self:: can not be used with php 8 but may be I am wrong.

Comment: Please ask all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You have an abstract class:

```
abstract class modSidePanelHelper {

  public static function getList($params) {
    // ...
  }

  public static function getGroupObject($params) {
    // ...
  }

  public static function loadMediaFiles($params, $module, $theme='') {
    // ...
  }

  public function renderItem(&$row, $params, $layout='_item') {
    // ...
  }

  public static function getLayoutByTheme($module, $group, $theme= '') {
    // ...
  }

  public static function getModulesEnable($params) {
     // ...
  }

  private function getModuleById($id) {
    // ...
  }

  static function getReturnURL($params, $type) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The only non-static function is `getModuleById`, which cannot be called from a static context of this class directly. You either have to create a new concrete class and call its instance then or make this function static.

In this case, I understand that making this class abstract is for preventing calling the constructor of this class, and this functionality is clearly only for static methods execution.

Then, replace:

```
  private function getModuleById($id) {
    // ...
  }
```

with:

```
  private static function getModuleById($id) {
    // ...
  }
```

I think you also have to do the same for the `renderItem` function, as long as it's not used here, it has to be executed in a static context if you need to execute it from some other place.

Comment: Thanks for answer but both of them did not work. Removing abstract word also did not work. Regards

Comment: I am not proficient in PHP that much, but it's clearly a problem with calling a constructor `new` in this code. You should be able to just execute the static method you've created.

Comment: @wisdom, can you share also what kind of problems you have once you'll remove the `self::` element? Can you share the location of this `helper.php` file in the Joomla's codebase?

Comment: Removing self:: turns back with an error code like this "Error Code: Call to undefined function getModuleById()". I have created a Joomla module this is the helper file of Module. No problem with php 7 but php 8 throws error codes

Comment: I don't know how that is supposed to work, when `getModuleById()` is a private, non-static function and you would call it from a static context of the same class. I have to check Joomla modules samples to understand why it even works. Do you call those functions from somewhere else? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @wisdom, does the `getModuleById()` has to be non-static? I don't see any references to non-static context here. It may be just static and that could work.

Comment: Yes you are right!! Thanks it worked after changing getModuleById function to static. thankyou very much

Comment: If you can provide support for Joomla questions, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and help us to resolve Joomla questions there. @Dawid